# Python program that generates addition

Tags: python

```
import random

num = 3
for i in range(num):
    print(random.randint(10,99), end=" + ")
```

Hey guys, I was wondering if you could help me with a little problem with my code.
The issue is that I want to get rid of the `" + "` at the end of an addition problem that the code generates.

Example of what the code generates so far:

```
31 + 42 + 64 +
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about splatting a list comprehension:

```
>>> import random
>>> print(*[random.randint(10,99) for _ in range(3)], sep = " + ")
41 + 36 + 92
```

Of course, you can also use str.join:

```
>>> print(" + ".join([str(random.randint(10,99)) for _ in range(3)]))
80 + 71 + 51
```